# Centering a List from the Left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list, centering

I have a un-ordered list with fairly large images in it. Now I wanted to see is there any css code I can use to center that list to where the first picture appears exactly in the middle of the page?

take a look at this picture for what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk7cZ.jpg

is there anyway to do this with css? or even javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here http://jsfiddle.net/ru79c/

I did it by just calculating how much of a margin there was between the difference of body width - image width divided by 2 for the left margin

EDIT
you could have this recalculate when the window resizes too, so it always stays centered.  http://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
var leftmargin = ($('body').width() - $('ul li').width()) / 2;
$('ul li:eq(0)').css({'margin-left':leftmargin + 'px'});
​
```

Comment: should mention it's using javascript in case you don't have it in your solution yet